# MySQL Index on first part of string

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm querying a very large table (over 3M records) in MySQL that has a category_id, subcategory_id and zipcode. The zip may or may not be 10 characters in the db.

The purpose is to get all the cat/subcat items w/in a certain radius of the specified zip. I have a function that returns a list of 5-digit zips for one specified. This list is then fed to my query like so...

```
SELECT whatever
FROM tblName
WHERE cat_id = 1
AND subcat_id = 5
AND LEFT(zip,5) IN (11111,22222,33333,44444,55555)
```

I have a compound index on cat_id, subcat_id and zip, but the zip being 10 characters in some cases may be throwing it off. Can I index the LEFT(zip,5) somehow?

Comment: Have you got the query plan for this query? That should tell you how it is currenlty working.should be useful to have that information before thinking about other indexes.

Comment: No you cannot use functions in indexes. You can in Oracle and PostgreSQL, but not in MySQL.

Comment: By "query plan" do you mean run EXPLAIN... on the query? I didn't think about that. Thanks. @Johan: I was thinking about Oracle I think... did PL/SQL a long time ago and thought this idea seemed possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question directly: yes, you can index left(zip, 5).

```
alter table tblName add index (zip(5));
```

And if you want the query to be able to use the index to search all columns:

```
alter table tblName add index (cat_id, subcat_id, zip(5));
```

Comment: [add index MySQL 5.7 Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) for those that would like to look up the detail

Comment: For mariaDB, [this doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#index-definitions) describes how to specify part of column in an index definition, basically it is the same syntax as shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a column with the normal 5 digit zip and column with all of the extra digits and let SQL handle it normally.  There are ways you could do what your talking about, but this is by far the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an index, change the query to:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM tblName
WHERE cat_id = 1
AND subcat_id = 5
AND (   zip LIKE '11111%'
     OR zip LIKE '22222%'
     OR zip LIKE '33333%'
     OR zip LIKE '44444%'
     OR zip LIKE '55555%')
```

Another option is to denormalize your table (should really be the last option) and add an extra field with that contains the 5 leftmost chars in zip.
Then you can do:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM tblName
WHERE cat_id = 1
AND subcat_id = 5
AND LEFTzip5 IN (11111,22222,33333,44444,55555)
```

Don't forget to put an index on field `leftzip5`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this one. It's a table we inherited of physician data (addresses, etc) and the zip is a varchar(255) which is inefficient. I thought about creating a char(5) of the LEFT(x,5) just to make the table smaller...it's 3M records and almost 900MB right now...