# Index first N characters of column

Tags: sql, mariadb

I don't have much experience with SQL databases and MariaDB, but for my understanding of how indexes work, I think there should be a way to index the first N characters of a SQL column.

Take as example the following strings in a column:

```
123abc
123def
123ghi
234fhg
234kgf
567kds
567ops
```

If I index just the first 3 characters, which are repetitive, I could get some performance gain during the `SELECT` operations because it would be split in 3 big blocks (123, 234, 567).

Is it possible? Or I'd have to add a second column with just the first 3 characters of each row and index it?

Comment: Actually, it's better if an indexed column has more unique values. If you have a lot of records but just a few unique values, usefulness of an index diminished.

Comment: I don't mean "just 2 or 3 unique values", I mean an enough high value to make index useful (and not so high to make it useless)

Comment: Its possible in mysql with a partial index,its used when the index would be too big for the number of characters but you still need a unique index.Whats your dbms?

Comment: What database are you using?  Can you give an example of the SQL you want to optimize?  And, an index on the full column will also speed your queries.

Comment: I think I would use MariaDB, but I'm talking about conceptual threads.   I've not yet a query, but it would be used to search in a ZIP codes database.

Comment: Here is a partial index for the first 3 characters in mysql probably it will work in Maria also `CREATE INDEX some_name ON table (column(3));`

Comment: An index on the full column can do all the things the partial one can + more. The only reason to use a partial index is when the column is too big or you want to save space, which is not the case if you are storing ZIP codes.

Comment: @Vatev I'm not sure you are right, an index on a list of ZIP codes would be useless because each row is unique.

Comment: @FezVrasta each row being unique is the best possible scenario for an index. Can you explain what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Assuming your table name is `tmp` and the column you want to index is `col`, this would be the way to create an index on the first 3 characters of the column:

```
alter table tmp add index first3Characters (col(3));
```

See also: [MySQL Index on first part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507440/mysql-index-on-first-part-of-string)